# PHP generating same random number at same time (in seconds)

Tags: php

I'm using random number function in a PHP script while uploading files. Because I wanted to avoid overwrite files with same name. So following is the script potion is used while upload the file.

```
$filename = rand(0,100000).strtolower($_FILES['file']['name']);
$dir="/file/upload/directory/".$filename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["user_file"]["tmp_name"], $dir);
```

This application expected to have large amount of concurrent users. So QA testing this application with different automated tools by applying high concurrent visit. That point the random number seems generating the same value within the same seconds.

Then we test the random number separately this same random number on same time was clearly identified.

While search on web some post suggest on `mt_rand()` but still it is same on milli second level.

Is there any way of generating random number in time independent way in PHP?

Comment: randomness is NOT a valid way to guarantee unique filenames. You WILL get collisions very quickly due to the birthday paradox.

Comment: You could hash date and set it as name of the file, so it wont have the same name for other files

Comment: If you want unique file names, use `md5_file()` to get a hash of the file and make that the name. Or at the very least use something like the first 5-10 characters. Chances are you won't hit a collision with that. The benefit of this is that if you hit the same hash for a file it is most likely that same file.

Comment: Assuming that you store the information in a database, you could use the auto-increment ID for the file-name.

Comment: By the way, I would also do some validation on `$_FILES['file']['name']` before I use it as a file-name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random numbers are generated with time. But for this particular issue we need to write few lines of code. If we check for file existence and apply incremental number to the file name it will be a fixed solution. The code can be like follows.

```
$filename = strtolower($_FILES['file']['name']);
$dir="/file/upload/directory/";
$i = 1;

while(is_file($dir . $i . $filename))
{
   $i++;
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["user_file"]["tmp_name"], $dir . $i . $filename);
```

Even though loop is inefficient. This will make sure the file overwrite won't happen.

Comment: Thanks. this is giving a fix solution even though random naming not applied.